# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 by default on Windows?

Tags: windows, driver, oledb

Is the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver by default on Windows 7 or is it already outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 has been superceeded by Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. I can't immediately think of any reason you'd need to use the older driver as the new one is much better.

Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is included with Windows 2000 though Windows 7 but will not work natively on any 64 bit OS.